# Refresh DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, refresh

I'm using a DataTable for a custom report and a DataView for searching a single record.

[image]

Here's my search code:

```
    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvReport.DataSource = new DataView(dt, "StudentID = " + txtSearch.Text, "StudentID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    }
```

Now what I want to happen is when I refresh the DataGridView, I want to display again all of the records. Any help? The **DataGridView.Refresh();** code doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Comment: The Refresh method only makes the DGV redraw itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set the data source back to the DataTable (dt)?

Answer (score 0):

Refresh will be working fine it's showing the result of your search.

Your refesh button needs to set the data source of thr report back to dt.